# Gerador de paginas PHP

Tags: php

Queria fazer mais ou menos como o Youtube, onde você preenche o formulário e depois é criada um pagina com o seu vídeo (meu site também vai conter videos), já fiz a parte do upload mas não faço ideia nem de por onde começar para gera uma pagina automaticamente. Poderiam me dizer uma linguagem de programação para isso ou se posso fazer pelo próprio php?

Upload:

```
<?php
    include("conexao.php");

    $msg = false;

    if(isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){

        $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4));
        $novo_nome = md5(time()) .$extensao;
        $diretorio = "upload/";


        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

        $sql_code = "INSERT INTO arquivo (codigo, arquivo, data) VALUES (null, '$novo_nome', NOW())";
        if ($mysqli->query($sql_code))
            $msg = "Arquivo enviado";

        else 
            $msg = "Falha ao enviar.";

    }
?>

<?php
    if ($msg != false) echo "<p> $msg </p>";
?>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Arquivo: <input type="file"  required name="arquivo">
    <input type="submit" name="Salvar">
</form>
```

Comment: Que página é essa do youtube que você se refere?

Comment: A pagina de upload, onde você preenche as informações como titulo, descrição e faz o upload do video.

Comment: Pode mostra o que vc já desenvolveu?

Comment: So o upload mesmo, um sistema bem simples para fazer upload de arquivos.

Comment: se vc não mostrar algum código, vão fechar a sua pergunta

Comment: Ok, sou novo aqui, é só colar aqui o codigo?

Comment: clica em editar e cola seu codigo

Comment: Olha acho que não deu muito certo só colar o código hein

Comment: acertei seu código

Comment: então, crie um arquivo cabecario.php e um arquivo rodape.php que serão incluidos na pagina que vai rodar o video

Comment: Mas  quando alguém fizer o upload eu queria que automaticamente já criasse uma pagina contendo o video, como se fosse o post de um blog.

Comment: Então, depois vc cria uma pagina incluindo esses dois arquivos, que vão caracterizar um modelo único para a pagina, só diferenciando o conteúdo. O conteúdo será composto do vídeo que o usuário enviar

Comment: Então, nessa parte eu pensei em somente deixar um código ja pronto e queria que quando a pagina fosse criada mudasse a src de um iframe, assim seria mais simples, meu problema mesmo está em como fazer uma pagina ser criada automaticamente com esse código depois do formulário ser enviado.

Comment: ai fica muito extenso e complicado explicar através de comentários

Comment: Mas você poderia so me dizer uma linguagem de programação ou algo para pesquisar?

Comment: PHP é uma opção boa

Comment: Obrigado vo ve se acho algo